# why div location matters in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a toy example (counter) and I wanted to display the output on an html page.
I found that the javascript code only works when div is "declared" before javascript code.
I thought the order of calling the div doesn't matter.

here is the simple code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Random Variable 3</title>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- div here (before js code) is working -->
    <div id="content2display1"; style="text-align: center; font-size: 80px;"></div>

    <script>
        let x = 0;

        function getRandom1() {

            x = x + 1
            document.getElementById('content2display1').innerHTML = x;     // content2display che viene mandato a html
            console.log("x: ", x)
            // return rv_i;
        };

        getRandom1();
        setInterval("getRandom1();", 1000);

    </script>

    <!-- div here is not working... -->
    <!-- <div id="content2display1"; style="text-align: center; font-size: 80px;"></div> -->


</body>

</html>
```

Why the code doesn't work when div is after the javscript code?

Comment: Because HTML is executed line by line from top to bottom. So first you have to render DOM elements and after this manipulate them with Javascript

Comment: what the @IvanBeliakov said. Otherwise, you will get a `reference error `that the element is null` which means that it does not know the element (yet). YOu can use the defer attribute or an `addEventListener` for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to defer the script and execute it after the whole document is read and loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your script before the div declaration, the div itself doesn't exist yet in the DOM and your "document.getElementById" returns null.

If you want to put your script before, you should wrap your script body into a DOMContentLoaded listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    //your script here
});
```

Doing so, the script waits for the entire DOM to be loaded before to be executed.

Comment: make your life easier and use `window.addEventListener...` instead of the `document.body`. alternatively the `defer` attribute on the script tag.